# FluentValidation Multiple error messages for one property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

i am validating input values with FluentValidation. i am using a method to validate value from database which return's integer value -1, -2 and -3 for different error messages on the base of value. how can i display error message according to the return value from method. i made a variable in class scope and set the return value and in next statement i tried comparison and try to display the message but i observe that next statement is executed before the updating value.

i want to display different error messages for one input value.

for example user input a negative value error message should be "negative values are not allowed",
if user input a large value number then message should be "number is too long".

here is code  **ISValidAction** is method which validates the input and set the variable returnvalue this method always returns true.

```
int returnvalue = 0;
RuleFor(r => r.action).Must(ISValidAction).WithMessage("Action does not exist in the system.").When(r => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.action));

RuleFor(r => returnvalue).Must(r => !(returnvalue != 1 && returnvalue != -2 && returnvalue != -3)).WithMessage("");//for -1
        RuleFor(r => returnvalue).Must(r => !(returnvalue != 1 && returnvalue != -1 && returnvalue != -3)).WithMessage("");//for -2
        RuleFor(r => returnvalue).Must(r => !(returnvalue != 1 && returnvalue != -1 && returnvalue != -2)).WithMessage("");// for -3
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i got the solution! for showing multiple errors against one value.

i just added error messages in `PropertyValidatorContext`

```
RuleFor(r => r.action).Must(ActionRateLimit).When(r => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.action));
```

this is call for validation using a function.

here is method.

```
private bool ActionRateLimit(LogActionInput obj, string actionName, PropertyValidatorContext context)
        {
        int result = 0;
        IRecognitionStoreService StoreService = new RecognitionStoreService();
        result = StoreService.ActionRateLimit(actionName, obj.userName);            
        if (result==1)
        {
           return true;
        }
        else if (result==0)
        {
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("ValidationMessage","Invalid action name or the user doesn't exists.");
        }
        else if(result==-1)
        {
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("ValidationMessage", "Action exceeds its rate limit. Please try again in a while.");
        }
        else if (result == -3)
        {
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("ValidationMessage", "This user has not completed the prequisite challenge. Action logging failed.");
        }
        return false;

        }

    }
```

it works fine.

Comment: I don't know why I am getting the error:  cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<string, bool>'

Comment: Had to add .WithMessage("{ValidationMessage}") after Must() to make it work

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can return different error messages based on value of one property.
for example, We have State (string) property and :

```
         RuleFor(x => x.State).Custom((st, context) =>
         {
            if (st == "0")
            {
                context.AddFailure("error message for (st == 0)");
            }
            if (st == "-1")
            {
                context.AddFailure("error message for (st == -1)");
            }
        });
```