# Fluent validation: It is possible to add more error messages?

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I have error model, for example

and rule in my validator

```
RuleFor(d => d.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is required.")
```

Is there any way to add a new custom option such as

```
 RuleFor(d => d.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is required.").**WithCustomErrorMessage("Example message content")**?
```

EDIT:
I want return list of errors from my web api app.
Every error looks something like this:

```
public class Error
    {
        public string ErrorName{ get; set; }
        public string ErrorDetails{ get; set; }
        public string ErrorCode{ get; set; }
        public string FieldPath{ get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to assign these values in the validator and then create a list of errors in my handler using the ValidationResult object.

Thank you for your advices.

Comment: What's the use case for this? Why do you need a regular error message and a custom error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FluentValidation Multiple error messages for one property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620454/fluentvalidation-multiple-error-messages-for-one-property)

Comment: I've just edited my post :)

Comment: Edited my answer for you

Comment: @Leito7 does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return custom error object with `WithState`, for example:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Ledger.LedgerDetails)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithState(x => Result<string>.Failure(new InvalidGeneralLedgerException("Can't add an empty ledger")))
```

Here Result is my custom object, in your case you can do

```
WithState(x => new Error() { ErrorName = "My custom prop name", ErrorCode = 69 })
```

This will return your custom object when the rule breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don’t you just edit the property inside ‘.WithMessage()’?
Edit:

As you now edited the question, i will add the answer here. Just to be clear you are missing some code on how you call your validator. That is needed to properly answer your question.

Making the assumption you want to return all errors here and that is in fact possible. Look at this link to retrieve all errors from the validation https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/error-codes.html

Answer (score 0):

Here I tried

```
  public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context,
                                       ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var errors = context.ModelState.Values.Where(v => v.Errors.Count > 0)
                        .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
                        .Select(v => v.ErrorMessage)
                        .ToList();

                var value = context.ModelState.Keys.ToList();
                Dictionary<string, string[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
                foreach (var modelStateKey in context.ModelState.Keys.ToList())
                {   
                   // here you can get your desire data
                    string[] arr = null ;
                    List<string> list = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var error in context.ModelState[modelStateKey].Errors)
                    {
                        // here you can modify as you want 
                        list.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                    arr = list.ToArray();
                    dictionary.Add(modelStateKey, arr);
                }
                // here you can make your own model and bind data as you want.
                var responseObj = new 
                {
                    StatusCode="400",
                    Message = "Bad Request",
                    Errors = dictionary
                };
 

        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(responseObj);
                return;
            }
            await next(); 
        }

Response Model example:// you can make your own model
{
    "statusCode": "400",
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "errors": {
        "Channel": [
            "'Channel' must not be empty."
        ],
        "TransactionId": [
            "'TransactionId' must not be empty."
        ],
        "Number": [
            "'Number' must not be empty."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).